# Partitions of values in a fibonacci call graph (call graph is a binary tree)

Tags: python, data-structures, recursion, combinatorics, fibonacci

I have an ongoing project investigating the Fibonacci sequence, this is just a personal project, I have created a binary `tree class` which makes a binary tree of the Fibonacci call graph, so for `f(3)` I generate the tree:

[image: Binary Tree]

I want to create a method of my `tree class` `get_partitions()` that traverses the tree to generate partitions of the `root value`, I regard here summands that differ in order as **different** partions; so for the example here of `f(3)`, the `get_partitions()` method would traverse the tree and yield:

```
Partion 1: 2,1
Partion 2: 2,1,0
Partion 3: 1,1,1
Partion 4: 1,1,1,0
Partion 5: 1,0,1,1
Partion 6: 1,0,1,1,0
```

As ultimately I want to enumerate every permutation of Fibonacci numbers that Partition the `root value`, in this case `3`, so for `Partition 1` enumerated would be `(2,1),(1,2)`, or `Partion 2` would be enumerated `(2,1,0),(2,0,1),(1,2,0),(1,0,2),(0,2,1),(0,1,2)`, etc…

[Edit 1] My concern is with `Partion 4` and `Partion 5` in this examples as enumerating all combinations of these partions would yield **duplicate** partions.

Would it be correct that the number of combinations for a given `root value` would yield a Catalan number?

My `Tree class` is:

```
class FibTree(object):
"""Class which builds binary tree from Fibonacci function call graph"""
def __init__(self, n, parent=None, level=None, i=None):
    if level is None:
        level = 0
    if i is None:
        i = 1
    self.n = n
    self.parent = parent
    self.level = level
    self.i = i # Node index value
    if n < 2:
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = n
    else:
        self.left = FibTree(n - 1, self, level + 1, i*2)
        self.right = FibTree(n - 2, self, level + 1, (i*2)+1)
        self.value = self.left.value + self.right.value
```

I'd be grateful of any help for producing the tree class method and any enlightenment on the maths to my problem.

[EDIT:] How I get my partions
All partions must sum to `Root` value:
`Partion 1:` Taken from Level 1 `(2,1)`
`Partion 2:` Use the `left child node` value of `root`, but now take the values of the children of the `right child node` of the `root` node `(1,0)`, to give a Partion of `(2,1,0)`
`Partion 3:` As traversal of `right child node` of the `root` node has been exhausted, traverse to next level of `left child node` value of `root` (level 2), and use the these child node values as first part of partion `(1,1)` then take the `right child node` value of the `root` node (1), to give a partion of `(1,1,1)`
`Partion 4:` Keeping the initial partion values from the previous partion `(1,1)`, but as with `Partion 2` take the values of the children of the `right child node` of the `root` node `(1,0)`, to give a Partion of `(1,1,1,0)`
`Partion 5:` As the left child, of the left child of the root, has children, use these as the first part of the partion `(1,0)` then take the right child value of the left child of the `root` (1), giving a partion so far of `(1,0,1)`, then take the right child node of the root `(1)`, to give a final partion of `(1,0,1,1)`
`Partion 6:` As Partion 5, take the first part of Partion 5 `(1,0,1)`, then as Partion 2 and 4 take the value of the child nodes of the right node of the root.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @svick the pseudo code for the method that produces all partion permulations. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason that you're letting `1` nodes have a `1` and `0` child?  It seems like the recursion should terminate there.  If not, one could make a case that you can have arbitrarily many `0` children, since they don't actually contribute anything.

Comment: Hi @templatetypedef to be true to the recursive Fibonacci function, at a terminating point `1` nodes do have a `1` and `0` child, but as you say it may be the arbitrary `0` children will ultimately prove to be no use to me as they have no magnitude, so I may need to filter them out in some way.

Comment: can you share how you generate your partitions... pseudo code or just English would be nice. I am a little confused as to how you get them.

Comment: Hi @johnthexiii Please see my edit where I have walked through how I arrived at the partions. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 1):

Here's an generator which produces the sort of values you want, but I haven't tried to find a fully optimised solution since your question is a bit confusing in places.

1. Are you sure about including 0?  Its not completely arbitrary because the maximum number of zeros in a partition is the number of ones (e.g. [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), but they don't seem to add anything.
2. How exactly do you order the partitions? When n=3, and ignoring zeros, they appear to be ordered by length, but if n=8, for example, is [2, 2, 2, 2] before or after [1, 2, 2, 3]?
3. Do you actually want a class to do this, or did you just use that as an example because it seemed the easiest way?

This code will yield all permutations of values in the fibonacci sequence which add to `n`, including `n` itself.  It will only work if `n` is actually in the sequence (e.g. `fibs(4)` will raise an exception).

Here's the code:

```
def fibs(n, _pairs=None):
    'Return partitions in the fibonacci sequence'
    if _pairs is None:
        # Generate a dict of fib numbers, values are the previous two numbers
        # E.g. {..., 8: [3, 5], 13: [5, 8], ... n: [fib_n-2, fib_n-1]} 
        a, b, c = 0, 1, 1
        _pairs = {1: [0, 1]}
        while c < n:
            a, b = b, a + b
            c = a + b
            _pairs[c] = [a, b]

    # Yield every sum combination of pairs
    yield (n,)
    if n == 1:
        yield (1, 0)
    else:
        right, left = _pairs[n]
        for vl in fibs(left, _pairs):
            for vr in fibs(right, _pairs):
                yield vl + vr
```

You can easily filter out duplicates using `set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in fibs(n))` and create permutations using `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: Thanks @aquavitae I'll look into your answer and get back; I saw partions being ordered depending on how a tree was traversed - a particular order as such isn't important. I've set this up as a `Class` of which I'm adding too - I'm finding this a good way of keeping things together, plus learning about binary trees, traversals etc... I'm not sure I need to include zero, but was going to to start off with, as zero is naturally yielded from recursively generating the Fib sequence. Thanks Alex

Comment: The above function `fibs()` doesn't seem to work for any value for `n` above `3`

Comment: There was one line missing which meant that the output was incomplete, but it seems to work for larger numbers for me.  What exactly doesn't work?  Is the output incorrect? Note that it will only work for values of `n` in the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Hi @aquavitae I called your `fibs(n)` function, like: `print list(fibs(4))` and it had a `Key error`; if I call the method with a lower number that 4: `print list(fibs(3))` it output a list of `1`'s and `0`'s.

Comment: 4 is not in the fibonacci sequence (see the note I added to my answer). Try 5 or 8.

Comment: Hi @aquavitae if I call the function `print list(fibs(8))` I get returned `[(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)]` as opposed to every sum combination of pairs. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I fixed a mistake in the code yesterday which resulted in that - just copy and try again.  Should work.